# Using beautifulsoup, how to scrape the table headers from a page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried using varying pieces of code for scraping the names of table headers using bs and python and each time i just get an empty list returned. This is the value I want to extract:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover data-grid ng-scope">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th class="ng-isolate-scope sortable" data-colname="Advertiser" data-colsorter="sorter">
           Advertiser
```

The info I would like to extract is the "data-colname". This what I've tried:

```
for tx in soup.find_all('th'):
    table_headers.append(tx.get('th.data-colname'))
#this returns an empty list, tried other combinations of this sort ... all returned an empty list

#Another attempt was:
spans = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.select('th.ng-isolate-scope data-colname')]
# returns errors
```

Comment: Can you tell me what `tx` represents in this case?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to extract the value from the attribute `data-colname` is with, for example:

```
for tx in soup.find_all('th'):
    table_headers.append(tx['data-colname'])
```

Here's the code I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover data-grid ng-scope"> <thead><tr><th class="ng-isolate-scope sortable" data-colname="Advertiser" data-colsorter="sorter">Advertiser</th></tr></thead></table'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table_headers = []
for tx in soup.find_all('th'):
    table_headers.append(tx['data-colname'])
```

Output:

```
>>> print table_headers
[u'Advertiser']
```

Comment: Hey mate - thx for the quick response - i'm still seeing the same empty list.

Comment: hmm, it's working for me. I used your html code above (just adding `</th></tr></thead></table>` at the end). What version python / beautifulsoup are you using? How do you initialize `soup`?

Comment: Currently using python 2.7.6, bs4. Im setting soup to a method that returns the html code. Using the for loop works fine when getting the links... but not on the "data-colname" attributes.

Comment: Weird. Anyway, I added the code I used above. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think removing the `th` from inside the `get()` should solve your problem.

Since `tx` it's already:

```
<th class="ng-isolate-scope sortable" data-colname="Advertiser" data-colsorter="sorter">
           Advertiser
```

Or its siblings, you only have the element you're dealing with one at a time.
So, long story short:

```
for tx in soup.find_all('th'):
    table_headers.append(tx.get('data-colname'))
```

Hope this helps.